# Intel integrated audio signal path

Tags: audio, motherboard, signal

I have a Dell Latitude C840 laptop.

It has Intel Integrated Audio. Intel 82801 CA/CAM AC'97 Audio Controller.

It has been giving me problems. Sometimes I get chopped or truncated audio, or strange sounds. Once it "goes bad", it continues until reboot. A couple of times the sound device was not found at boot.

I do not think it is a loose connection, or at least not after the signal has been made analog.

How is audio created in this type of a system? Does the main processor (Intel) talk digitally to a sound controller IC, which then uses a DAC to drive an amplifier that drives the speakers? Would the sound controller IC be physically soldered onto the motherboard or is it placed on a seperate board?

The problem gets worse in hot weather.

I thought that the electronics forum users might have more insight on this problem than the computer forum users.

Comment: some audio codec or DSP chip that drives a small output stage, probably integrated DAC.

Comment: So there is a digital signal path from the main processor to an external chip that could be faulty.

Comment: Why is it called integrated audio, if it uses an external chip?

Comment: There is a dedicated audio bus on the motherboard and the controller lives on the chipset/southbridge , it is used both for audio output and modem interfaces. Audio chip is on this bus and the data is transfered in the AC'97 protocol, how the chip drives the analog circuitry depends on the device used.

Comment: The Audio DSP is integrated, AC'97 is the last link to talk to a chip dealing with the analog circuitry, its basically an inteligent DAC on something better than I2C. It is also possible that the chipset integrates the DC97 and codec.

Comment: Integrated graphics has a analog coding chip actually generating the physical signal too.

Comment: I believe that modem is bad on this laptop. Is it conceivable that a bad modem would corrupt the audio bus?

Comment: Unlikely to be an actual hardware (signal path) fault. If hot weather is involved, suspect CPU temperature causing speed throttling, and scheduling so bad it can't keep up with audio demands. Especially if you're downloading movies at the same time. Or disk drive approaching death, so retries are needed to correct read errors. Or driver bugs, so that the drivers are scrambling the audio DSP's settings : check for OS updates on these.